# massive insertions in mongodb with python

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x

I'm using python + MongoDB with pymongo so far everything is fine

But now I want to optimize the inserts, what I do is read with cds with 50000 rows and I create a loop to read the row of a row, passing a json and perform insertion (insert), it takes a lot but XD

Problems now I have about 200 csv files that has between 50000 and 150000 rows and it already becomes unsustainable

**I wanted to know if there is any way to do bulk inserts in MongoDB**

Example in postgress is the copy instruction, which uploads a complete file to the bd

Thanks in advance, regards 
Translated by google translate, to English   :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, take a look [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/). Depending on the format you can use [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) directly.